# Does one need to worry about registration when staying in Russia (Moscow) for 6 working days and 2 weekends?

Tags: russia, moscow, registration

I've seen different sources saying that "one needs to register in Russia within the first 7 working days", and other sources saying that "one needs to register in Russian when staying for 7 working days or more". Those may sound like just the semantics, but they have two  different meanings. What is the actual rule, and do I need to worry about registration in my case?

Comment: If you are staying at a hotel or hostel they should deal with the registration for you.

Answer (score 3):

Per [WayToRussia.net](http://www.waytorussia.net/RussianVisa/Registration.html), which isn't official but is usually pretty darn spot-on, and cites the law in question as a reference:

> Every foreigner who comes to Russia should have his/her Russian visa
>   registered within 7 working days upon arrival, **excluding holidays and
>   weekends**.

So you're *theoretically* OK.  But they go on to say:

> Before 25 March 2011 you had to be registered within 72 hours upon
>   arrival (excluding weekends and holidays), so it might be that not all
>   the authorities are aware about this new rule yet ... we strongly
>   recommend you to register your visa in 72 hours (only working days
>   count) upon arrival.

So it's probably worth doing anyway, just for peace of mind and/or in case your schedule changes (what happens if your flight is cancelled?).  Since registration is actually the responsibility of whoever you're staying with, this should not be much of a hassle.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is that you have to be registered within 7 working days of your arrival. Source from the [Russian Migration Service](http://www.fms.gov.ru/government_services/migrate/), referring to foreign citizens temporarily residing in Russia:

> временно проживающий или временно пребывающий в Российской Федерации иностранный гражданин - по истечении семи рабочих дней со дня прибытия в место пребывания

Translation:

> a foreign citizen temporarily residing or temporarily staying in the Russian Federation - after seven working days since arrival to the location of their stay

However, the registration is not your obligation if you're staying as a hotel. The same page goes on to list exceptions and says

> находится в гостинице или в иной организации, оказывающей гостиничные услуги [..]

meaning

> is located in a hotel or another organization offering hotel services [..]

If you are going to be staying at a hotel or similar, then the hotel will handle your registration. You will already have the necessary paperwork, as they need a passport and a migration card, which you will receive just before you enter the country.

In your case, if you're leaving before the 7th workday, you're fine without a registration, but your hotel will probably register you anyway.